# array.indexOf is just -1

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

got that code:

```
var itemGrid = [3,4,2,11,1,3,5,8,6];
var a = itemGrid.indexOf(0);
```

a is everytime `-1`. It should be `3`. What did I do wrong?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/okg9g4tt/

Comment: its because you are searching for 0 in the array

Comment: array.indexOf(n) returns the position of n in the array. if n is not in the array it returns -1. in this case 0 is not present so -1.

while array[n] returns value present at nth position in the array

Comment: `indexOf` will give you the index of(!) the element `0` ... which is not part of the array, so the result is `-1`. If you want to get the zero index element of the array, just do `var a = itemGrid[0]`

Comment: if you want to get the first value which is 3 u should do itemGrid[0] and not with the indexOf(0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding.

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) will not get the element **at** index 0, it will

> return the first index at which a given element can be **found** in the
>   array, or -1 if it is not present.

If you want the element at index 0, you should simply do `itemGrid[0]`

Answer (score 3):

This is becuase `0` is not a value in your initial array.
The function then returns -1. ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf))

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

To return the value at index 0, use `itemGrid[0]`

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

`.indexOf()` is not supported by IE8 and below so pay attention if you plan to support these browsers.

Answer (score 2):

0 is not an element of that array.
So its index is being returned as -1;

probably you want to have
 **itemGrid[0]** which will return 3

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
itemGrid[0]
```

**indexOf(0)** would return the **position** of the value 0 in the array, but there is no 0 in the array.

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` returns index of found element. Here `-1` is returned because 0 is not found in your array.

**NOTE:** `indexOf` will get you the position of the element if found, so when you do `itemGrid.indexOf(0);` , it means you are looking for the position of the element **'0'** which is not present in your array and hence it is returning `-1`

Answer (score 1):

> a is everytime -1. It should be 3. What did I do wrong?

```
var itemGrid = [3,4,2,11,1,3,5,8,6];
var a = itemGrid[0];   // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

array.indexOf(n) returns the position of n in the array. if n is not in the array it returns -1. in this case 0 is not present so -1.

while array[n] returns value present at nth position in the array

Answer (score 0):

"0" is not present in the Array, so it will return -1.

Answer (score 0):

> `IndexOf` `(IndexOf<T>(T[], T))`

Searches for the specified object and returns the index of its first occurrence in a one-dimensional array.

your example tries to find the first indexof 0 returning -1, meaning no 0's where found.

To return the first index in your array use the indexer `ItemGrid[0]`